# In "aa67bc54c9", is there any way to print "aa" 67 times, "bc" 54 times and so on, using regular expressions?

Tags: regex

I was asked this question in an interview for an internship, and the first solution I suggested was to try and use a regular expression (I usually am a little stumped in interviews). Something like this

```
(?P<str>[a-zA-Z]+)(?P<n>[0-9]+)
```

I thought it would match the strings and store them in the variable "str" and the numbers in the variable "n". How, I was not sure of.

So it matches strings of type "a1b2c3", but a problem here is that it also matches strings of type "a1b". Could anyone suggest a solution to deal with this problem?

Also, is there any other regular expression that could solve this problem?

Comment: Not an answer, but I couldn't resist quoting this : "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 'I know, I’ll use regular expressions.' Now they have two problems." -- Jamie Zawinski

Comment: That Jamie Z quote is one of my favourites too.

Comment: Pascal MARTIN - Would you enlight me, why do they have two problems? (I really want to know). ---- About the question, I think the RegEx looks right to me and it does not seems like it should match 'a1b'. Are you sure it does, Siddhant?

Comment: There are contexts where regular expressions make most sense.

Comment: @NawaMan : it's just that I really too often see (unreadable and unmaintenable) regex used in situations where they are not the best possible tool for the job -- and that too many people, when faced a problem, immediatly think "I'll use a regex", not considering whether this is the best solution. ;; regex are fine, sometimes, and can be fun to write, I admit ; but they are too often a pain to understand/maintain :-(

Comment: @NawaMan: Many people think that because regular expressions look to cryptical they must be a universal weapon to solve nearly any problem.

Comment: I think a regex is a good solution to this problem.  See my answer below.

Comment: @tster: Regular expressions are part of the solution but not *the* solution itself.

Comment: @NawaMan - It does. I'm not able to figure out why. 
And yes even I agree that regular expressions sometimes do make the job tougher. But like I said, this was an impulse response (I've just started appearing for interviews. :-) ), and I was curious about what could be the correct solution to this problem using Regex. I know the other solution is pretty understandable. But then regex are, like, intriguing. :-)

Comment: @Pascal MARTIN - I am really sick of that quote. I know that there are places where regular expressions are inappropriate, but there are other places where they are the perfect tool for the job. Granted, his task can't be done _entirely_ in regular expressions, but using a regular expression can certainly help him get there faster.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

how about:

```
while ($line =~ s/^([a-z]+)(\d+)//i)
{
    print $1 x $2;
}
```

Comment: using regex is too easy in your language, in java i would have to write a lot more.

Comment: @01: Then maybe you are using the wrong language?  Or maybe you should not use regexes in your language?  Or maybe you need a better regex library in your language.

Comment: Don't most languages now have Perl-style regular expression libraries?

Comment: Could technically be done in one single regex: `$line =~ s/([a-z]+)(\d+)/print $1 x $2;""/ieg;` Also, can be done without destroying the original string, if you change the loop condition to `$line =~ /([a-z]+)(\d+)/ig`

Comment: @Chris, you should call that a single _Perl_ regexp.

Answer (score 33):

Do you know why "regular expressions" are called "regular"?  :-)

That would be too long to explain, I'll just outline the way.  To match a pattern (i.e. decide whether a given string is "valid" or "invalid"), a theoretical informatician would use a [finite state automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_automaton#Acceptors_and_recognizers).  That's an abstract machine that has a finite number of states; each tick it reads a char from the input and jumps to another state.  The pattern of where to jump from particular state when a particular character is read is fixed.  Some states are marked as "OK", some--as "FAIL", so that by examining state of a machine you can check whether your text is "valid" (i.e. a valid e-mail).

For example, this machine only accepts "nice" as its "valid" word (a pic from Wikipedia):

[image: a picture from Wikipedia article referenced above]

A set of "valid" words such a machine theoretically can distinguish from invalid is called "[regular language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language)".  Not every set is a regular language: for example, finite state automata are incapable of checking whether parentheses in string are balanced.

But constructing state machines was a complex task, compared to the complexity of defining what "valid" is.  So the mathematicians (mainly S. Kleene) noted that every [regular language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language) could be described with a "[regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Definition)".  They had `*`s and `|`s and were the prototypes of what we know as regexps now.

---

What does it have to do with the problem?  *The problem in subject is essentially non-regular.*  It can't be expressed with anything that works like a finite automaton.

The essence is that it should contain a memory cell that is capable to hold an arbitrary number (repetition count in your case).  Finite automata and classical regular expressions can not do this.

However, modern regexps are more expressive and [are said to be able to check balanced parentheses](http://perl.plover.com/yak/regex/samples/slide083.html)!  But this may serve as a good example that you shouldn't use regexps for tasks they don't suit.  Let alone that it contains code snippets; this makes the expression far from being "regular".

Answering the initial question, **you can't solve your problem with using anything "regular" only**.  However, regexps could be aid you in solving this problem, as in [tster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483757/in-aa67bc54c9-is-there-any-way-to-print-aa-67-times-bc-54-times-and-so-on/1483785#1483785)

---

Perhaps, I should look closer to [tster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483757/in-aa67bc54c9-is-there-any-way-to-print-aa-67-times-bc-54-times-and-so-on/1483785#1483785) (do a "+1" there, please!) and show why it's not the "regular expression" solution.  One may think that it is, it just contains print statement (not essential) and a loop--and loop concept is compatible with finite state automaton expressive power.  But there is one more elusive thing:

```
while ($line =~ s/^([a-z]+)(\d+)//i)
{
    print $1 
             x  # <--- this one
               $2;
}
```

The task of reading a string and a number and printing repeatedly that string given number of times, where the number is an **arbitrary integer**, is undoable on a finite state machine without additional memory.  You use a memory cell to keep that number and decrease it, and check for it to be greater than zero.  But this number may be *arbitrarily big*, and it contradicts with a *finite* memory available to the *finite* state machine.

However, there's nothing wrong with classical pattern `/([abc]*){5}/` that matches something "regular" repeated **fixed** number of times.  We essentially have states that correspond to "matched pattern once", "matched pattern twice" ... "matched pattern 5 times".  There's finite number of them, and that's the gist of the difference.

Comment: Beautiful images; interesting commentary.  I'm just not sure about 'the problem in the subject is essentially irregular'.  It is very regular - but not doable just with regular expressions.

Comment: the regular expression in my answer is using only a regular grammar, no extensions.  It's just that it also loops and prints in Perl.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: thanks for pointing it out, I'll use another word.  @tster:  I'll edit my answer with a scrutiny of your solution and why it's not "using regular grammar".

Comment: It should be remembered that all real computers are finite state automata, as they have a finite amount of storage. So though in a theoretical sense a FSA is "incapable" of certain things, in practical terms it is quite capable enough for our purposes. The analogy here is that you could write a regex that was *long enough*, containing enough repetitions for your practical needs. But it would be less convenient than using a mix of regex and procedural looping in the host language. So it's not a matter of things being possible/impossible, but just convenient/inconvenient.

Comment: @Earwicker: we apply computer science not only to reason about theoretical possibility.  We apply it to rule out the approach ("use regular expressions **only**") by reasoning that it contradicts the nature of concepts we consider.  So I'd like to make matters you're talking about as a comment, to appearing of which I actually was looking forward. :)

Comment: @Earwicker, a computer is not a Finite State Automata as it certainly has a place to store information outside of its internal states. A computer is more accurately a Linear Bounded Automata (LBA), that is, a Turing Machine with a non-infinite tape.

Comment: @Falaina: Turing machine with finite tape *is* a finite state automaton. In my PC there is only 200 Gb of "tape" (i.e. harddrive), and this makes it a FSA.  That's what Earwicker was talking about.

Answer (score 7):

Answering your question directly:

- No, regular expressions match text and don't print anything, so there is no way to do it solely using regular expressions.

The regular expression you gave will match one string/number pair; you can then print that repeatedly using an appropriate mechanism.  The Perl solution from @tster is about as compact as it gets. (It doesn't use the names that you applied in your regex; I'm pretty sure that doesn't matter.)

The remaining details depend on your implementation language.

Answer (score 4):

Nope, this is your basic 'trick question' - no matter how you answer it that answer is wrong unless you have exactly the answer the interviewer was trained to parrot. See the workup of the issue given by Pavel Shved - note that all invocations have 'not' as a common condition, the tool just keeps sliding: *Even when it changes state there is no counter in that state*

I have a rather advanced book by Kenneth C Louden who is a college prof on the matter, in which it is stated that the issue at hand is codified as "Regex's can't count." The obvious answer to the question seems to me at the  moment to be using the lookahead feature of Regex's ...

Probably depends on what build of what brand of regex the interviewer is using, which probably depends of flight-dynamics of Golf Balls.

Comment: I disagree with your 'trick question' assessment.  As I read the question, at least, the interviewer only specified the input and desired output.  Using a regex to get from point A to point B was the OP's idea, not a condition imposed by the interviewer.

Comment: @Dave: Noted, and correct. I missed the how to get there was OP's idea: OP states "I was asked this question in an interview for an internship" from which I inferred that OP I was asked this question in an interview for an internship - the fact that I flamed the interviewer comes from industrial environments that I work in where 304 Stainless wraps such interviewers with protective gear that is toothless and cannot be used in the manner directed.

If you're a "Pro From Dover" it is worth the effort, too often it is the Master Crypto Thesis candidate vs someone who actually runs a shop.

Answer (score 2):

Nice answers so far. Regular expressions alone are generally thought of as a way to match patterns, not generate output in the manner you mentioned.

Having said that, there is a way to use regex as part of the solution. @Jonathan Leffler made a good point in his comment to [tster's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483757/in-aa67bc54c9-is-there-any-way-to-print-aa-67-times-bc-54-times-and-so-on/1483785#1483785): *"... maybe you need a better regex library in your language."*

Depending on your language of choice and the library available, it is possible to pull this off. Using C# and .NET, for example, this could be achieved via the [Regex.Replace method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace.aspx). However, the solution is not 100% regex since it still relies on other classes and methods (StringBuilder, String.Join, and Enumerable.Repeat) as shown below:

```
string input = "aa67bc54c9";
string pattern = @"([a-z]+)(\d+)";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, m =>
        // can be achieved using StringBuilder or String.Join/Enumerable.Repeat
        // don't use both
        //new StringBuilder().Insert(0, m.Groups[1].Value, Int32.Parse(m.Groups[2].Value)).ToString()
        String.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat(m.Groups[1].Value, Int32.Parse(m.Groups[2].Value)).ToArray())
         + Environment.NewLine // comment out to prevent line breaks
        );
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

A clearer solution would be to identify the matches, loop over them and insert them using the StringBuilder rather than rely on Regex.Replace. Other languages may have compact idioms to handle the string multiplication that doesn't rely on other library classes.

To answer the interview question, I would reply with, "it's possible, however the solution would not be a stand-alone 100% regex approach and would rely on other language features and/or libraries to handle the generation aspect of the question since the regex alone is helpful in matching patterns, not generating them."

And based on the other responses here you could beef up that answer further if needed.

Comment: Excellent, if the interviewer can understand it.