# Can D be compiled into platform independent code?

Tags: linux, windows, cross-platform, d

I See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510989/can-c-be-compiled-into-platform-independent-code-why-not), and I would like to know if I could do something similar with D.

More specifically, I am developing from a Linux machine, with x86_64 processor.

I am targeting

- Linux machines with x86_64 processor (not the biggest problem)
- Macs with x86_64 (should be doable...)
- Windowes with x86_64 - This is where the cross platform issues come into play. As a part time developer without any access to windows machine, and reluctancy to get one, I am more interested in platform independant coding than porting to windowes.
- Windows with i686 (32 bit) - is that even possible to compile code for both 64 bit and 32 bit targets?

Project is currently on a Linux machine, and uses entirely the standard Phoboes library, and the import part is, it heavily uses LuaD and some C source compiled to *.o files.

Comment: How is [tag:C] relevant to the question whether D can be compiled into intermediate-code?

Comment: I thought the fact that I am interfacing *.o s written in C with the main project written in D could play a role?

Comment: It's completely ir-elephant that the source of those object files was C.

Comment: Okey, I did not know that when tagging . I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

D makes it very easy to write portable source code, as the standard library provides abstractions for many OS-specific APIs. Otherwise, the same answers for C++ will generally apply to D, although currently all implementations compile D to native code.

You can generate Windows binaries by running a Windows D compiler under Wine. In theory, cross-compilation should be possible with GDC and LDC, but I don't know how mature it is with either toolchain.

Comment: The problem is, i think the concept of *.o files does not work under windowes. You need to use "dll"-s . Can you pack the same stuff that is inside a *.o in a dll ? or other their some specific problems? I mean how does these two actually compare? Considering I have zero knowledge of faildoes, I cant really make much out of the google search results.

Comment: It is pretty much the same. `.o` -> `.obj`, `.a` -> `.lib`, `.so` -> `.dll`. One major difference is that you need an import library to link against a DLL, but if the DLL exports have names, you can generate one using `implib`.

Comment: Writing portable source code is a different story from the original question. Cross-compilation also does not generate "platform independent code", as we all know...

Answer (score 3):

If [D.NET project](http://dnet.codeplex.com) succeeded you would have an answer. Current state is that there is no D compiler which targets JVM or CLR, or any other VM. All current D compilers compile into the native machine code. I dreamed of starting a project to make D compiler which targets JVM, but unfortunately have no time for such (enormous) project.